# How to turn off rounding numbers in FloatField model?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I have got problem when I was saving latitude and longitude data from google maps to my database in FloatField model.

And when there are numbers which have a lot of integers after comma the FloatField form django is automatically rounding them.

For example from google maps I get coordinates:

```
latitude': 49.82895324990301, 'longitude': 21.160517976135225
```

And in my database the saved values are:

```
latitude': 49.828953249903, 'longitude': 21.1605179761352
```

So the saved numbers are rounded and I dont know how to disable it. I will be very thankful for every help.

Field in my models.py looks like:

```
class MuseumLocation(models.Model):
owner = models.ForeignKey(User)  
name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
location = models.CharField(max_length=150, null=True, blank=True) 
latitude = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True)
longitude = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True)
```

Comment: Try to change `latitude ` and `longitude  `  FloatField to Decimal Field.

Comment: I test use `FloatField` works perfect in my case. Can you please post your key codes?